# indentifier backgroundSubtractorMOG syntax error

Tags: c++, syntax-error, opencv3.0, background-subtraction

Hello i am learning OpenCV motion detection program and currently i have this error saying 'syntax error:identifier BackgroundSubtractorMOG'
Here is the code

```
int main()
  {
string file_name, video_out;
Mat res, frameMOG, background, framegray, backgroundgray, prevframe;
int w = 0, h = 0, x = 0, y = 0, i = 0, j = 0, fps, fourcc = 0;

int enteredregion = 0;
int index = 0;
int currArea, prevArea = 0;
int cardetected, prevframecar;

//Reading Filename from user
cout << "Please enter file name without spaces: ";
cin >> file_name;
video_out = "output.mkv";

//Creating VideoCapture object for opening file
VideoCapture cap(file_name);
if (!cap.isOpened())
{
    cout << "Could not open file";
    return -1;
}
//Mog object creation for background subtraction
Ptr<BackgroundSubtractor> ptrMOG;
ptrMOG = new BackgroundSubtractorMOG(); //      <-error points here
cap.read(background);
```

I also encountered another error   *(): is not a member of cv:BackgroundSubtractor*

```
 frame.copyTo(current);
    GaussianBlur(current, current, Size(9, 9), 0, 0, BORDER_DEFAULT);
    cvtColor(current, framegray, CV_BGR2GRAY);
    medianBlur(framegray, framegray, 9);

    ptrMOG->operator()(framegray, frameMOG);  // <--error points here
    //absdiff(backgroundgray,framegray,frameMOG);
```

Currently i dont know how to get around this errors. I am currently using Visual Studio 2013 and OpenCv 3.0. Here is my library:

```
   #include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
   #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
   #include <iostream>
   #include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
   #include <opencv2/video/background_segm.hpp>
```

Comment: Follow this [tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d1/dc5/tutorial_background_subtraction.html).

Comment: Thank you i changed the MOG to MOG2 and the operator() to 'apply' and it worked